# How to delete object in Algolia by specific key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have a object with this data.

```
{
     _id:"5ec6cdf648fdd1678c6f20a6",
     title:"Abc",
     objectID:"35922720"
}
```

How can I delete data by `_id`?

Note, this is a custom property and not the standard Algolia property `objectId`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to delete items in an Algolia index:

- **Delete Object:** which deletes an object by the Algolia applied `objectId`. [More here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#delete-object).
- **Delete By Query:** which deletes objects meeting a supplied query. A limitation of this is that it only supports a few options of query (numeric, facet, or tag) and geo queries. [More here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#delete-by)

Based on this, you can delete an object directly using "Delete by Query" if it can be selected by a supported query option. If it cannot be deleted using Delete by Query, then you would need to retrieve the objects and delete them by the Algolia standard `objectId` property.

In this scenario, `_id` is a custom string property so you cannot use "Delete by Query", but would need to perform a select query first to retrieve the object's standard `objectId` property.

If you wanted to use Delete By Query and could modify the index, you could convert `_id` to a numeric field. Your id is a hexadecimal number in string representation so one approach could be to convert this to a decimal representation.

For example, if your object's custom `_id` property was numeric like the following, you could delete it using "Delete by Query".

```
{
  _id:12345,
  title:"Abc",
  objectID:"35922720"
}
```

The Delete By Query params would be:

```
{
  "params":"numericFilters=_id=12345"
}
```

See more on [Numeric Filters here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/numericFilters/).

In the future, you may able to delete by a hexadecimal number as [hexadecimal is supported in JSON5](https://json5.org/) but it would still need support by Algolia and a change in representation in your index. In this scenario, your object would look like:

```
{
  _id:0x5ec6cdf648fdd1678c6f20a6,
  title:"Abc",
  objectID:"35922720"
}
```

Comment: I want to delete object by _id or title not by objectID.So please suggest me for that way.